# PHP version of nbuilder or other class hydration methods?

Tags: php

Is there anything in either the base PHP framework or a stand-alone library that is simular to [nbuilder](http://nbuilder.org/)?

I am working in a SOA based architecture and I'd like to create fakes until the API is complete. I've hand rolled most of the fakes but there is one entity that has a large object graph that I'd like to use a tool for.